# Error 'Method not allowed' ajax jquery when url has parameters (Laravel)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

javascript returns a error 'Method not allowed' when it calls to url has parameters.

```
HTML
1.- <a href="{{ URL::to('acceso', ['option'=>'1']) }}">Acceso</a>
2.- <a href="{{ URL('acceso') }}">Acceso 2</a>
```

First option return a error. Second option work well.

This is the Route:

```
Route::get('/acceso/{option?}', function ($option = '') {   
   return view('acceso_Usuario')->with('option', $option);
});

Route::post('call', 'example_Controller@function_example');
```

This is the Controller:

```
class example_Controller extends Controller
{
   public function function_example(Request $request)
   {
       if ($request->ajax()) {

           return response()->json([
           ]);

       }
   } 
}
```

and this is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var route = "call";
    var token = $("#token").val();

    var parameters=
    {
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: route,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: parameters,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (msj) {
            alert("Error Ajax);
        }
    });

 });
```

someone who can help me! :)

Comment: Change this contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', to  contentType: 'application/json',

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript is making a POST request, but the matching route is defined as allowing only GET,HEAD requests (`with Route::get()`).

Comment: he has `Route::post('call', 'example_Controller@function_example');`,so he should be able to post

Comment: @madalinivascu yes, but he stated that the first url is the one with the error, and that doesn't match the 'call' route.

Comment: i don't know how the first lines of code are related to the javascript, he is calling an ajax at document ready to a different route, his question makes no sense

Comment: I agree, it's a little unclear. However, the error indicates that the route being hit doesn't allow the method being used, and I'm working from the code provided

Answer (score 1):

change your ajax url

```
var url = '{{url("call")}}';
```

pass csrf token using this way in post method

```
headers: {

    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

},
```

Answer (score 0):

change your route into

```
 var route = '{{url("call")}}';
```

this will generate a absoulte url to your route

Answer (score 0):

Already solved! I explain my problem because I like that the questions are always solved for when other colleagues have the same problem.

The problem is that adding a parameter to the URL changes the root directory of the javascript file. The solution that I have tried is to introduce 'dynamically' the root directory of our website and in this way Ajax will look for the function correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   **var currentDirectory = window.location.href;**
   **var rootDirectory = currentDirectory.substring(0, currentDirectory .indexOf("public") + 6);**

   **var route = rootDirectory + "/call";**
   var token = $("#token").val();

   var parameters=
   {
   };

    $.ajax({
    url: route,
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: parameters,
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (msj) {
        alert("Error Ajax);
    }
   });

});
```

Thank you all for your help! :)

Comment: if you had used my answer you shouldn't had that problem because laravel would give you the absolute url to that route